# Android : c2md implementation

Tags: android-c2dm

I am implementing the c2md, in phone android 2.2,
  I have follow the all the steps from http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

and use the php code from [C2DM implementation PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121508/c2dm-implementation-php-code) ,i get response id=0:1323075593128502%2fd4838f00000031  but i can not get the notification of phone.also i have try with command prompt.
Does anyone idea where i have made the mistake.

Also register the account on google.

Comment: I have check out the issue here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106318/android-c2dm-port-number-choice][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106318/android-c2dm-port-number-choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewall issue, probably? Try when the device is on 3G, as opposed to WiFi.