# How to verify C2DM connectivity

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106318/android-c2dm-port-number-choice) that C2DM uses port 5228 for connection.

Is there a ping address (or something) I can use to test connectivity to the C2DM servers easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the port, but to check connectivity I'd be inclined to send a test message to a test registration ID. That'll test all the way through the stack.

Though even if the servers are up, there's no guarantee the message will be delivered, so I'm not sure doing what you propose will add much.